# Django Sign-in page. Passing arguments in Formname.objects.get(email=email, password=password))

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

I am creating a **sign in** page using **Django**. I want to know whether *if i can directly use the variables* **"email** and **password"** and **pass** them in **query**, to check dynamically, whether if email id and password exists in data base, and if it does, then Dashboard.html site should open directly....

```
try:
    u = RegisterForm.objects.get(email="ram@gmail.com", password=12345678)
```

**Although when i hard code the email id and password(This exists in database) it runs successfully.** (as shown ABOVE).

```
def mainpage(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")

        try:
            u = RegisterForm.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
            return render(request, 'Dashboard.html')

        except Exception:
            return render(request, 'Homepage.html')
```

Am i doing it the wrong way. Pls suggest me right way if i am doing it wrong. **But before suggesting me right way pls help me solve above query.**

*When i input MY EMAIL and MY PASSWORD, i want it to get stored in Email, Password variable. And i want to use it in query to check whether if the Email And Password that i gave exists in my database or not.*

And the variable name is same as the column name in the table....!

Comment: Why do you need to check if the password exists?..

Comment: Every Unique id has a password....  if both matches then only the main page should be visible.......and u = RegisterForm.objects.get(email=email, password=password) will do this if i am not wrong........this will check whether if both the fields match or not in database.

Comment: Why don't you just use the appropriate `authenticate` method?

Comment: well i wanted to try this basic logic first...:) So if u can help me......it would be great for me to understand a few logics :)
 Although i would love to learn this way too.. can u please tell me what changes i should make to my code to use authenticate method

Comment: Please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/

Comment: Thankyou....:) can u help me achieve my logic too, the one i was talking about previously...?

Comment: by usin u = RegisterForm.objects.get(email=email, password=password) @jonrsharpe

Comment: My way Worked :) I succeeded in making it work my way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my way worked..

```
def mainpage(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")

        try:
            u = RegisterForm.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
            return render(request, 'Dashboard.html')

        except Exception:
            return render(request, 'Homepage.html')
```

This is the simplest sign-in Implementation if you are unaware of Django-Authentication, and if you want to make sign in page as a newbie.

To test it without actually taking data from the database you can use following code line...

```
try:
    u = RegisterForm.objects.get(email="abc@gmail.com", password=123456)
```

Here *RegisterForm* is my model name in models.py file.

Hope this helps other new-ones/newbies like me.....Happy programming